# Assigning Z Value to DEM Raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, elevation, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I am working on projecting a DEM raster in ArcScene to drape some 2D imagery over it, and ran into a snag. Upon further analyzing my DEM TIF file, it does not have an attribute table, which lead me to find that it does not have a z-value for elevation.

This DEM raster is 10m imagery located over a mountain in Maine, and I would prefer to figure out how to attach a z coordinate to this dataset. Is there a way to add a z coordinate to this layer, or should I start searching for other datasets?

Comment: Height is encoded to the value of a pixel. No need for attribute table.

Comment: If the DEM is 4-byte float, it's not possible to build a VAT (only integer types need apply)

Answer (score 1):

As user30184 points out, the raster values of a DEM are the heights, so no further data is needed.  In ArcScene, you must specify what to use for the heights when you are draping a layer.  See [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/3d-analyst/setting-a-raster-layer-s-base-heights-using-a-surface-in-arcscene.htm) and [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/3d-analyst/fundamentals-of-displaying-surfaces-in-3d.htm) on how to do that.

So, basically, you would pull in your 2D imagery to ArcScene and tell it to use the DEM as the height (following the instructions in the link).  There should be no more to it than that.

Comment: Thank you both! @MappGnosis, that clears up some of my issue. My remaining is that the drape disappears when I assign it to a float on a custom surface. I've found it produces a ton of vertical columns, but nothing more. Any thoughts?

Comment: What format is your drape?